# Recreate efficiently this figure

Tags: tables, math-mode, technical-drawing

I am writing a technical document, and I need to explain several steps of a construction which use matrices and linear equations. I was puzzled how I would create my figures and one paper I reference use this : 
[image: how a step look like]

I have to do 6 or 7 of these, and I would like to know what is the most efficient way of doing it. In each figure the number of components and the value of equation will be different. I already know how to create individually matrices and tables. I want to know how to produce such a figure without too much sweat. I don't use latex a lot, but if you point out packages, references or any material to look at it will be a good start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use TikZ for that, but I’m not sure if this is the most efficient way, since I don’t understand how your images will differ from each other. So you only want to change some numbers in the equations?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
% load extra stuff
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,matrix,positioning,fit}
% some settings and style definitions
\tikzset{
    boxed eqns/.style={% 
        matrix of math nodes,
        row sep=-0.4pt,
        nodes={
            draw,
            minimum width=1cm,
            minimum height=0.6cm,
        },
    },
    values/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        left delimiter=[,
        right delimiter=],
    },
    equation/.style={
        execute at begin node={$\displaystyle},
        execute at end node={$},
    },
    blue box around/.style={
        draw,
        ultra thick,
        blue,
        fit=#1,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    cancel/.style={
        cross out,
        draw,
        red,
        ultra thick,
        fit=#1,
        inner xsep=10pt,
        inner ysep=1pt,
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (Variables) [boxed eqns] {a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\};
    \matrix (Values) [values,right=of Variables] {1\\2\\3\\};
    \node (Eqn) [equation,right=of Values] {a_1+a_2+a_3};
    \foreach \l in {1,2,3}
        \draw [->] (Variables-\l-1) -- (Eqn);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (Variables) [boxed eqns] {a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\};
    \matrix (Values) [values,right=of Variables] {1\\2\\3\\};
    \node [blue box around=(Variables-2-1)] {};
    \node [cancel=(Values)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**How to get the upper picture?**

1. Create the styles for different parts of your images.

   - I used matrixes, that switch to math mode for their content
   - I let the matrices draw the frames and delimiters
2. Set up the `{tikzpicture}` environment.
3. Draw the first matrix with the boxed variables.

   - Us the `boxed eqns` style.
   - Give a name to it in braces, e.g. `(Variables)`.
   - Use `\\` after *each* variable, even the last one.
4. Draw the second matrix with the values.

   - Us the `values` style.
   - Give a name to it in braces, e.g. `(Values)`.
   - Use `\\` after *each* value, even the last one.
   - Postion it right of the first on with `right=of Variables`.
5. Draw the node containing the equantion.

   - Us the `equation` style.
   - Give a name to it in braces, e.g. `(Eqn)`.
   - Postion it right of the first on with `right=of Values`.
6. Draw the arrows

   - Use `\foreach` to repeat the things for every item of the list `{1,2,3}`,
     and save the current item in `\l`.
   - Set up the `\draw` command with `->` to get an arrow tip at the end.
   - Begin the path at `(Variables-\l-1)`, which is one of the first matrix’ cell.
   - End the path at `(Eqn)`. The best end position is calculated automatically.

**How to get the lower picture?**

1. Draw the matrices as above.
2. Use `blue box around=(<node name>)` to frame a node or part of a matrix*.
3. Use `cancel=(<node name>)` to put a cross over a node or part of a matrix*.

<sub>* The part of a matrix is a node …</sub>

**How to draw an equation system?**

Add this definition to `\tikzsset`

```
eqn system/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row sep=0.1cm,
    column sep=0.5cm,
    draw,
    nodes={
        anchor=base east,
    },
},
```

and use it like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (ES) [eqn system] {
        a_1   & + 2a_2 &        & + 4a_4 \\
        10b_1 &        &        & -3b_a  \\
              & -  c_2 & + 3c_3 &        \\
    };
    \node [blue box around=(ES-1-1) (ES-1-4)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result 2]

But this needs some improvements as you can see in the image …

### Update

You could automat the things with a new macro

```
% \autodraw{<Varaibles>}{<Number of Variables>}{<Values>}{<Eqn>}
\newcommand{\autodraw}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (Variables) [boxed eqns] {#1};
        \matrix (Values) [values,right=of Variables] {#3};
        \node (Eqn) [equation,right=of Values] {#4};
        \foreach \l in {1,...,#2}
            \draw [->] (Variables-\l-1) -- (Eqn);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

example

```
\autodraw{b_1\\b_2\\b_2\\}{3}{7\\2\\5\\}{2b_1+b_2-3b_3}
```

Comment: Wow this is powerful! Seems like a complete language by itself, like matlab. I modified your script with :                \matrix (Variables) [boxed eqns] {a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_6\\a_7\\};
    \matrix (Values) [values, right=of Variables-2-1] {1\\2\\3\\};
    \node (Eqn) [equation, right=of Values] {a_1+a_2+a_3};
    \foreach \l in {1,2,3}
        \draw [->] (Variables-\l-1) -- (Eqn);

Comment: yes I want to modify the content of `Variables`, `Values` and `Eqn`. My guess will be to write a macro to put the arguments at the right position. Is there a better way??

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yes TikZ is very powerful and can do even more complex things like this. It’s a user level layer of PGF which was created to do graphics. Have a look at the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), which includes some great tutorials to learn TikZ.

Comment: @UmNyobe: I added a command to draw the things. You surely find a better name that `\autodraw` for it ;-)